# SSIS Web Service Task: "Index was outside the bounds of the array" Error when accessing empty array

Tags: xml, web-services, ssis

I'm trying to connect to a webservice and pull in some data using the webservice task in SSIS 2005. I am able to download the WSDL file and I'm able to see the methods in the Webservice Task. I provide the necessary parameters through variables (I've even tried hardcoding the parameters). However, when I execute the task I keep getting the error message 'Index was outside the bounds of the array'. This occurs when the web service returns an empty array. It seems like SSIS should handle this error. Please help to find a work around for this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in SSIS, check if you have the latest Service Pack - it might fix it. For SSIS 2005 I think it is currently SP3 and there were couple cumulative updates (CU) on to of it. Don't really know if it fixes the particular issue, but that would be the first thing I try.

Comment: I had been using 2008 R2 since then in evading this problem, therefore I am accepting this answer. Thanks.